# How to avoid duplicating a lot of php prepare 12+ times

Tags: php, mysqli

```
try  {$db=mysqli_connect( etc )
catch {
        retry on time out
        handle errors
}

try { if (!($errors = $db->prepare("insert into errors (`insert`,`error`) values(?,?);
    print "\n*********prepare Error:" . $db->error;
}
}
catch { repeat above}

try {$errors->bind_param("ss",$sqlLoad,$errormsg); }
catch {repeat above)
....
try {$error->execute()} catch {repeat above error handling}
```

Now repeat all of that 10-40 times for different SQL queries on different fields.

That is a lot of duplicated code.  Make my code hard to read, and if someone wants to add more sql queries they are forced to reduplicate large blocks of code.

I was thinking something like this but ran into a stumbling block with bind.

```
$sql[0]=array("name","select ? from <tablename>","s");
$sql[1]=array("name","select ?,? from <tablename>","ss");
$sql[2]=array("name","select ?,?,? from <tablename>","sss");
$sql[3]=array("name","select ?,?,?,? from <tablename>","ssss");

for(i=0;i<=3,i++){
try (
$preQuery[$sql[i][0]=$db->prepare($sql[i][1]);}
catch {}
try {$preQuery[$sql[i][0]]->bind_param($sql[i][2],????);}  //Here is the trouble how do I define unique variables
catch {   }
}
```

Here is some real code
It is a work in progress

```
foreach ($fieldspath as $field)
{
$filepath=$_SERVER[$field];
$result=$queryfile->execute();
$getres = $queryfile->get_result();
$numRows = -1;
$numRows = $getres->num_rows;

    if ($numRows <>0)
    {
      $qryField = $getres->fetch_assoc();
      $_SERVER[$field]=$qryField["id"];
      $fileCount=$qryField["count"];
      $fileRating=$qryField["rating"];
      mysqli_query($db, "update Files set count=count+1 where `id` ='" . $qryField["id"] . "';");
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
    $output = $insertFile->execute();
    $result = $queryip->execute();
    $getres = $queryip->get_result();
    $qryField = $getres->fetch_assoc();
    $_SERVER[$field]=$qryField["id"];
    }

}
```

Notice:  How I can re-execute a query just by:
$result=$queryfile->execute();

The query doesn't have to be re-stated, nor do the parameters.  Everything is automatic.  The actual queries are all listed at the top of the program, and I never have to see them, or restate them ever again.  Also I don't need to cram my parameters into array before I can use them.

```
<?php
$pipeName = '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$db = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket='.$pipeName.";dbname=dbase", $username, $password);

$sql["errors"]="insert into errors (`insert`,`error`) values(:insert,:error);";
$sql["events"]="insert into event (`message`) values(?);";
$sql["queryip"]="select id,count,rating FROM ip where address=? limit 1;";
$sql["queryUsrAgent"]="select id,count,rating  FROM http_user_agent where agent=? limit 1;";
$sql["insUsrAgent"]="insert into http_user_agent (`agent`) values (?);";
$sql["insertIP"]="insert into ip (`address`) values (?);";
$sql["insertReqURI"]="insert into request (`REQUEST_URI`) values (?);";
$sql["queryReqURI"]="select * FROM request where REQUEST_URI=? LIMIT 1;";
$sql["queryfile"]="select id,count,rating FROM Files where path=? limit 1;";
$sql["insertFile"]="insert into Files (`path`) values (?);";
$sql["cntIp"]="update ip set count=count+1 where `address` = :ip";
$sql["cntFiles"]="update Files set count=count+1 where `id` = :id;";
$sql["cntAgent"]="update http_user_agent set count=count+1 where `agent` = :agent;";
$sql["reqRequest"]="select *  FROM request where REQUEST_URI= :requesturi LIMIT 1;";
$sql["cntRequest"]="update request set count=count+1 where `REQUEST_URI` = :requesturi;";

$ready=doPrepare($db,$sql);

$ready["errors"]->execute(array("insert"=>"stuff","error" =>"stuff"));
pdoRun($ready,"errors",array("iniisert"=>"iiiii","error" =>"yyyyyggg"));

function doPrepare($db, $enmass) {
    foreach ($enmass as $key => $sql) {
    try {
         $stmt[$key] = $db->prepare($sql);
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "\nStuff";
        trigger_error($e);
        return false;
    }
    }
    return $stmt;
}

function pdoRun($ready,$query,$vals) {
    try {
          $ready[$query]->execute($vals);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "\nExecution fail";
        }

}

//       $stmt->execute(array_values($column_values));


?>
```

Comment: You can put it inside a function or something, so that instead of re-typing the codes all over again, just type the function with the proper parameters.

Comment: `$ok = MySafeConnect( $db ); // by ref`  .... and so on

Comment: @Swellar  A function might be able to deduplicate some of the error handling.  Then I still have to duplicate all the regular prepare,bind,execute statements 10-40 times.  Also the bind statement requires 1 or more strings values to complete the substitutions and they have to be uniquely named to avoid overlap.

Comment: I would recommend you to use php framework

Comment: @MuhammadIbnuh  Which framework?  Show me an example! I am relatively new to php so I need an example.

Comment: @cybernard Laravel is probably the industry standard right now in PHP.

Comment: @cybernard what are you using for your editor? You should also get a plugin that automatically formats your code into PSR-2 standard as it seems as though you don't have any guidelines you're using

Comment: @Jonathan I have not yet, had any large multi-file projects, so I am still using **vi**  If you have suggestions, I am listening.

Comment: Get yourself Sublime Text 3. It's very good. If you get Sublime you can also use a vast number of plugins as described in a prior comment, you could get one that parses your PHP into a standard format http://www.php-fig.org/. I understand the desire to want to learn raw PHP first. It is a good idea. You should try to keep doing that for a while before jumping into a framework. But you should perhaps find a good book on PHP and a good text editor. O'Reilly "Modern PHP" is one I highly recommend.

Comment: @Jonathan Right now I am having trouble with the **DRY** concept covered in the book you recommended.

Comment: @cybernard it means Don't Repeat Yourself. Whenever you write a piece of code that is being used more than once, you ought to consider making that piece of code modular so it can be called where ever it is required. Repeating yourself is bad practise because it quickly becomes a nightmare when you need to update the code; for example, you might forget to update it in every location.

Comment: @Jonathan  I know what it means, but I find myself in a situation  where I may have to repeat myself dozen if not hundreds of times.

Comment: @cybernard so don't is the simple answer. That's the point. Think of chunks of code as different jobs. If you can label some chunk of code as serving a particular purpose, and if that code is reused, modularise it and reuse it as a module. If you don't get it at first it doesn't matter. Don't let that hamper progress in reading, you will learn much more rapidly if you just read.

Answer (score 0):

Making prepared queries like you are doing doesn't work like you seem to think it does. The parameter placeholders can only substitute for literal values. You can't use them for column names or table names or anything else.

You also can't prepare a query like `"select ? from"` because it names no table. It's not a syntactically complete query.

The better practice is to code a "helper function" that does the prepare and execute for you. You can reduce repetitive code that way.

By the way, I find PDO is much easier than Mysqli when coding a helper function like this, because you don't have to use the `bind_param()` with variable arguments. In PDO, you just pass an array of arguments to `execute()`.

```
function doInsert($db, $sql, $params) {
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        trigger_error($e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now call it this way:

```
$sql = "insert into errors (`insert`, `error`) values(?, ?)";
$success = doInsert($db, $sql, [$sqlLoad, $errormsg]);
```

You might even like the function to format your INSERT statement for you:

```
function doInsert($db, $table, $column_values) {
    $placeholders = array_fill(1, count($column_values), '?');
    $columns = implode(',', array_keys($column_values));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($columns) VALUES ($placeholders)";
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array_values($column_values));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        trigger_error($e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$success = doInsert($db, "errors", ["insert"=>$sqlLoad, "error"=>$errormsg]);
```

You'll have to do something to apply back-ticks to the column names too.

Comment: **You also can't prepare a query like "select ? from"**  Yes, I know this, but I didn't feel it was necessary to show the whole query.  Anyone who knows sql would get the correct idea.

Comment: @cybernard: It's good that you know this would be an invalid query, but there are so many people who post bogus, made-up syntax on Stack Overflow that I try not to make assumptions. You should be more clear when you post your question. Either show the actual code you are using, or else use placeholder text like `"select ? from <tablename>"`

Comment: In order to avoid **id** burning, I end up repeating similar queries.  Which is why I want a list of pre-prepared queries statement to avoid copying and pasting the same queries over and over again.  SQL select id from ip where ip=<ip>".  If not, insert it, and then do another query to retrieve the id.  I have tried automatic methods, but they always burn ids.  I heard about lastid, but in a multi-threaded environment, lastid might not be the lastid from my thread, but another thread.

Comment: @cybernard: No, the last_insert_id is always the last inserted id from the same connection. This won't change if other concurrent connections are inserting. You can verify this: open two terminal windows and start the mysql client. Insert to a test table and then `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` from each window.

Comment: You should use a separate db connection in each thread. Then last_insert_id cannot be "polluted" by other threads.

Comment: I have been modifying a version of the code sample above doInsert #2.  I unset the $db to test if it would catch the error, and it doesn't.  The program dies out.

Comment: @cybernard, trying to call a method on a non-object is not an exception, it's a fatal error. It can't be caught. **This is like the most common PHP question on Stack Overflow.**

Comment: Ok.  I just tried it on a new routine $ready[$queryname"]-execute($vals);  This time I had a misspelling.  $vals=array("in888sert"=>"iiiii","error"=>"test");  Invalid parameter, didn't catch that either.  Yes, I had try {  } catch around that.

Comment: @cybernard: I can't follow what you're talking about when you put fragments of code in a comment like that. Edit your original question at the top, and post the code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Okay I see now. I really think you're on the wrong track when you prepare *all* the queries. You won't necessarily need them all, and prepared queries do use resources inside the MySQL server. So you're using resources perhaps needlessly.

Comment: Also you're using mysqli instead of PDO, and you haven't enabled exceptions in mysql. My apologies for not noticing this before. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Comment: I use every single query I prepared.  I have a db with 70+ columns, and I will need even more prepare statements before my program is complete.  I am just showing you a pdo "proof of concept" before I convert my whole program.  If the proof of concept doesn't work I am not going to change 300+ lines of code.  I will set the setting you described and get back tonight.

Comment: well **$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);** I finally caught an exception after days and days of effort.